# How do I use Gmail for a domain that I own that does not currently have email hosting?

Tags: gmail

My domain is www.example.com, and I want to use mike@example.com in Gmail.  Note that I do not have any kind of email hosting, so I would need to modify the DNS on the domain to point to an email server.

Does Gmail (maybe via a paid subscription) allow private domains to be used for email through their servers, and if so, how would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1):

Google offers [Gmail for work](https://www.google.com/work/apps/business/products/gmail/) which will allow you to use gmail with our own domain name.

> Paid Gmail features include: custom email (@yourcompany.com), unlimited group email addresses, 99.9% guaranteed uptime, twice the storage of personal Gmail, zero ads, 24/7 support, Google Apps Sync for Microsoft Outlook, and more.

They do not mention that you *must* be a registered business to use this service so it *may* be possible to use this as an unregistered business. You would need to  contact them to find out for sure.

Comment: Didn't this used to be called "Gmail for business"? Or have they changed the product?

Comment: Not 100% sure but I think they just tweaked the name